# c - pthread_create identifier

Tags: c, multithreading

The first argument of `pthread_create()` is a `thread` object which is used to identify the newly-created thread. However, I'm not sure I completely understand the implacations of this.

For instance, I am writing a simple chat server and I plan on using threads. Threads will be coming and going at all times, so keeping track of `thread` objects could be complicated. However, I don't think I should need to identify individual threads. Could I simply use the same `thread` object for the first argument of `pthread_create()` over and over again, or are there other ramifications for this?

Comment: The thread object is there to keep track of threads for cleaning up when the thread exits. If you plan to reuse the thread parameter, make sure you set the detach state to true when creating threads This will tell the main process that the cleanup can be done as soon as the thread exits.

Answer (score 2):

If you throw away the thread identifiers by overwriting the same variable with the ID of each thread you create, you'll not be able to use [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) to collect the exit status of threads.  So, you may as well make the threads detached (non-joinable) when you call [`pthread_create()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html).

If you don't make the threads detached, exiting threads will continue to use some resource, so continually creating attached (non-detached) threads that exit will use up system resources — a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_create.html

According to it:
"Upon successful completion, pthread_create() shall store the ID of the created thread in the location referenced by thread."

I think `pthread_create` just overwrites the value in the first argument. It does not read it, doesn't care what is inside it. So you can get a new thread from `pthread_create`, but you can't make it reuse an existing thread. If you would like to reuse your threads, that is more complicated.

Comment: There is repercussion in not tracking threads when they are created with detach state set to false. The main process will not cleanup after the threads exited. To clean up, the main thread must join them. In the OPs case, the threads should be created with detach state set to true so automatic cleanup can be done.

Comment: Optionally each thread can just call `pthread_detach` on itself i.e. `pthread_detach(pthread_self())`

Comment: Also, if you don't reap your own threads, your parent (recursively up to INIT) will do. So it's not that bad... iff you close shop yourself early enough.

Comment: So the short answer to the original question is "yes"

Comment: The original question wasn't just asking for "yes" or "no" answer. It also asked what's the ramification of doing it his way. Thus the need to explain a bit.